# Recurrent sequence $15x_nx_{n+2}-9x_{n+1}x_{n+2}-4x_{n}x_{n+1}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is a standard method to find the general term of the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_0,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$
15x_nx_{n+2}-9x_{n+1}x_{n+2}-4x_{n}x_{n+1}=0?
$$

Comment: Divide the general term with $x_nx_{n+1}x_{n+2}$ to get a simple linear difference equation for $y_n=\frac{1}{x_n}$. Then sort out the edge cases when one element is zero (if they are relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming initially that $x_n\ne 0$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, The recurrent relation can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{15}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{9}{x_{n}}-\frac{4}{x_{n+2}}=0
$$
or for a new sequence $y_n=1/x_n$,
$$
4y_{n+2}=-9y_n+15y_{n+1}
$$
Clearly, $y_n=c_1w_1^n+c_2w_2^n$, where $w_1,w_2$ are the roots of the quadratic form
$$
4t^2-15t+9=0,
$$
which are $w_1=3,$ $w_2=3/4$.

Comment: Interesting observation about rearrangement of initial equality. I think the roots of the quadratics are 3 and 4/3, but I understood the idea.

Comment: "Clearly" ... if you know hot to solve recurrences  :)